# AWS::S3::Errors::InvalidAccessKeyId in rails using paperclip gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip, aws-sdk

I get this error on signup with an uploaded image but I've already set my AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID in heroku config and triple checked that they are correct.

here is what I have in my development environment

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],

  }
}
```

here is my production environment

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
```

Here is my aws.rb initializer (I get a missing credentials error without these two lines)

```
AWS.config(
access_key_id: 'your_access_key',
secret_access_key: 'your_secret_access_key')
```

and finally here is my paperclip.rb initializer

```
# config/initializers/paperclip.rb
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
```

Any suggestions as to why I'm getting this invalid access key error?

```
AWS::S3::Errors::InvalidAccessKeyId in Devise::RegistrationsController#create
The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

Comment: `access_key_id: 'your_access_key',` ... You actually have your access key, here, right?  Probably starts with `AKIA...`

Comment: Its true that my access key starts with AKIA... are you suggesting that I put my actual access key and secret access key in my aws.rb initializer? I feel like that would be dangerous bc when I push to github it's public for all to see?

Comment: It needs to get there somehow, yes... those strings are placeholders... although you're correct not to commit it to github. The secret, especially, must be kept secret.  You'll need another way to set the key and secret... perhaps from environment variables?

Comment: I feel like i've tried everything.  My key and secret are set in heroku config.  I got desperate and even tried to add the key and the secret directly into the aws.rb initializer I get this error-  AWS::S3::Errors::AllAccessDisabled in Devise::RegistrationsController#create
All access to this object has been disabled

Comment: The bucket, key id, and secret access key are all set in heroku config but I get "something went wrong" in production even though the environment variables are set.  Locally I get the "AllAccessDisabled" if I put the key and secret into the 2 aws.rb placeholders.  Does AWS not play well with Devise?

Comment: have you found any solution so far ?

Comment: Have you set a user with the right permissions on aws side as well?